# Code running fine in debud mode (step-by-step) but stops before end when activated by button

Tags: excel, vba

I have read multiple of theese discussion and they all answers seems to be code-specific.
When i run my code from the button, it exits just before the last line and therefor doesnt delete the last range.. If i pres the button again, the rest is deleted.
Tried all sorts of ways to work around the problem - if sentence being the latest. Hope you guys can help

If sentences, While loops, delay via wait command between the last lines.

```
Sub NewFileNoPrices_Click()

Dim i As Long
```

Inserted as edit: (Might cause the problem further down)

```
Dim mySheetNames() As Variant

i = 0

mySheetNames = Array("Exchange Rates", "Raw Prices", "Summing Parts")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

On Error Resume Next

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(mySheetNames).Delete

On Error GoTo 0

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

From original post

```
Do While i < 2
i = i + 1

If i = 1 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ordering Tool").Columns("I:AI").Delete xlLeft
End If

If i = 2 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product Cost Tool").Rows("60:97").Delete xlUp
End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Furthermore i want to add more to this sub - All coding after I delete the first range isn't executed in full speed, but works fine in debug mode..

Comment: Are you sure? Insert a line `Msgbox "Deleting Range"` just before `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product Cost Tool").Rows("60:97").Delete xlUp` and now check if you see the messagebox?

Comment: Another way to check if the rows are getting deleted or not is to highlight the rows say Yellow. Do you still see yellow rows after the code is run?

Comment: Is this all the code for that Sub? Or have you copied only the code you think is relevant? Perhaps you've got some error trapping in there also that's failing? Alternatively, do you perhaps have an Event enabled that might be interfering?

Comment: Thanks for the comment CLR. I have now updated my question with the rest of the code in the sub. Found that the bottom part actually works alone - just not with the rest. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This is rather strange, as it should go into the second "if" as well. Try to use this code:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim i As Long
    i = 0

    Do While i < 2
        Debug.Print i
        i = i + 1
        If i = 1 Then
            MsgBox i
        End If

        If i = 2 Then
            MsgBox i
        End If
        Debug.Print i
        Debug.Print "-------"
    Loop

End Sub
```

And see how it works and whether it sends both 2  msgboxes. If this is not the case, then debug a bit further and find out why both the `MsgBox` are not visible.
This is how the immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+G) should look like after running the code:

[image]

Comment: Same thing happens here.
Immediate window response 0
One Msgbox saying: 1

Comment: Might be because of some preveous code..
I have this before my Do... Loop - Thouhgt it wasn't relevent.

'Dim mySheetNames() As Variant' 
 
'mySheetNames = Array("Exchange Rates", "Raw Prices", "Summing Parts")'

'Application.DisplayAlerts = False'

'On Error Resume Next'

'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(mySheetNames).Delete'

'On Error GoTo 0'

'Application.DisplayAlerts = True'